# Creating a Package - VisualForce page is missing

Tags: visualforce, unmanaged-package

I created a new VisualForce page - an exact copy of the last one I developed, but with a different name and the same controller code, but with a different name. So, now I want to create a new package (due to the last one not working properly with constantly changing names of classes following a naming convention). But I cannot see my new page in the Package Manager. I could see it in the list of VF pages in Setup and I have assigned all the neccessary user permissions to it. Why am I not able to see it in the list in the Package Manager, this is strange to me, as I am following the exact same procedure and order of doing things as before. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not already in the manifest? If the page has dependencies on existing objects, it would have been automatically included.

Comment: By manifest do you mean the list of available pages/classes etc. within the Package Manager?

Comment: Yes, check the list of current components in your package. Typically, you'd see that the dependent components are automatically included.

Comment: So, what I am trying to add is a VisualForce page and when added it automatically adds its controller. The problem is I cannot see the page itself. I just tried creating a blank page (nothing inside) and see it will appear, but apparantly it is not appearing either. I enabled all possible profiles. May be I must enable something else?

Comment: Permissions on an object have absolutely *no* effect on if you can add something to a package (you do need to have the ability to create/manage packages, though). I've never heard of a situation where you can't add a particular visualforce page to a package. I think some screenshots might help out here.

Comment: Ok, there you go: https://imgur.com/a/VoRQG

Comment: You've posted a few questions regarding creating packages. There are better ways to deploy between organizations. Have you used change sets?

Answer (score 0):

Some components are not automatically added to the package:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_components_auto_added.htm

Try to add the new VF and controller class using the standard procedure:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=adding_package_components.htm

Comment: The thing is page is not visible to be added, it is not that it is not added automatically, I cannot add it manually

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to go to the next page. Look at top-right corner of the list for the previous/next page options, or click on "V" in the "Rolodex" to show pages that start with V:

[image: Pagination and Rolodex feature]

Comment: So, basically the problem was that I was pressing on Next Page, but as nothing happened, I thought these are all the pages that are available. Basically, I just renamed the page to start with an A, so it could appear above on the list. But this is a temporary solution. I thought this might be a browser issue ( I am using Chrome), so I tried FF, button still does not work. Have you heard of anyhing like this before?